how to stop body from scrolling while in menu
When I'm in the menu and try to scroll my whole page scroll at the same time. I tried to add overflow hidden but it is ignored I think. I looked everywere on the internet but I can't find anything useful. If I add overflow hidden in the body the whole page will stop scrolling.


nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #1b1b1b;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 50px 0 100px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

nav .logo {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

nav ul li a.active,
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #111;
  background: #fff;
}

nav .menu-btn i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  nav {
      padding: 0 40px 0 50px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 920px) {
  nav .menu-btn i {
      display: block;
  }


  #click:checked~.menu-btn i:before {
      content: "\f00d";
  }

  nav ul {
      position: fixed;
      top: 80px;
      left: -100%;
      background: #111;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      display:block;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
      z-index: 2;
      overflow: hidden;
  }


  #click:checked~ul {
      left: 0;
  }

  nav ul li {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 40px 0;
  }

  nav ul li a {
      width: 100%;
      margin-left: -100%;
      display: block;
      font-size: 20px;
      transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  }

  #click:checked~ul li a {
      margin-left: 0px;
  }

  nav ul li a.active,
  nav ul li a:hover {
      background: none;
      color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  }
}
<nav>
    <div class="logo">
        NavBar
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="click">
    <label for="click" class="menu-btn">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </label>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#">Acasa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Prices</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">General</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>



How can I solve this?

I believe you can achieve this with JavaScript, you set the overflow to hidden on the body when the menu is toggled open and remove it when the menu is closed.
Try the code below;
const checkbox = document.getElementById('click');

checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.body.style.overflow = this.checked ? 'hidden' : 'auto';
});

The script has to be in the body tag of the html, when I do this, I usually put it just after the body tag before any other code, thats just personal preference, but I believe it can go anywhere.
Also remember to remove the overflow: hidden; from the nav ul in the css file.
Alternatively you can take a look at this how to create a responsive top navigation from W3 school.
Link: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp
Hope that helps :)
